# PM2 can't write to log file in cluster mode

Tags: pm2

I am converting an application to run in cluster_mode. After making the necessary additions the ecosystem.config.js file, the application fails to start due to a permission denied error:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/node/.pm2/logs/appplication-25.log'
[2019-08-06 09:48:55] PM2 log: App name:application id:25 disconnected
[2019-08-06 09:48:55] PM2 log: App [application] with id [25] and pid [18291], exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
[2019-08-06 09:48:55] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:application id:25
[2019-08-06 09:48:55] PM2 log: App name:application id:24 online
[2019-08-06 09:48:55] PM2 log: App name:application id:25 online
/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js:202
      throw err;
      ^
```

The PM2 God Daemon is running as the root user. The root user also owns the $PM2_HOME/logs directory.

```
$ ls -al /home/node/.pm2
total 328
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root    199 Aug  6 09:48 .
drwxr-x---. 5 node node     66 Aug  5 15:20 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 112548 Aug  6 08:29 dump.pm2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 112562 Aug  2 11:43 dump.pm2.bak
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  32768 Aug  6 03:07 logs
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    312 Apr 23 12:04 module_conf.json
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root     27 Apr 23 12:04 modules
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 Aug  6 09:48 pids
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  51170 Aug  6 09:48 pm2.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      4 Aug  5 15:19 pm2.pid
srwxrwxr-x  1 root root      0 Aug  5 15:19 pub.sock
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      0 Aug  6 09:48 reload.lock
srwxrwxr-x  1 root root      0 Aug  5 15:19 rpc.sock
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     13 Jul 26  2018 touch
```

ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'application',
    script: 'index.js',
    instances: 2,
    exec_mode: 'cluster_mode',
  }]
};
```

The application has been running in fork mode just fine. To test out cluster mode I ran:

```
pm2 delete application
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --uid node
```

The result:

```
--- PM2 list -----------------------------------------------
┌───────────────────────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬────────────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ App name                  │ id │ mode    │ pid  │ status  │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem        │ user │ watching │
├───────────────────────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼─────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼────────────┼──────┼──────────┤
│ application                  │ 25 │ cluster │ 0    │ errored │ 45      │ 0      │ 0%  │ 0 B        │ node │ disabled │
│ application                  │ 24 │ cluster │ 0    │ errored │ 45      │ 0      │ 0%  │ 0 B        │ node │ disabled │
```

Adding group write permissions to the logs directory, e.g. `chmod 775 $PM2_HOME/logs`, allows write access to the logs but I'm not sure why.

using Node.js v8.94 and PM2 v2.10.3